# Mongo Query for 2 values in array list in a document field

Tags: mongodb, list, field

I have a document in a collection that has a field called "myList", it has list items and I need to be able to query collection documents that have field "status" of "good" and "doneBy" with a value of "system" in the "myList" field:

```
[collection].myList
[
    {
    "location" : "3826487.pdf",
    "status" : "good",
    "time" : ISODate("2017-06-27T20:03:46.512Z"),
    "reportIdx" : 0,
    "doneBy" : "System"
    },
    {
    "location" : "rt-0.pdf",
    "status" : "bad",
    "time" : ISODate("2017-06-28T16:24:16.559Z"),
    "reportIdx" : 0,
    "doneBy" : "System"
    }
]
```

It should return all documents that have a list item qualified by the first one in this list. Even though the second list item has "bad", it should return this collection doc with "myList" having these 2 list items.

I figured out that a search for one of the fields would be this but how to do both , I'm not sure of the syntax.

```
 db.getCollection('[collection]').find({myList  : { $elemMatch : { "status" : "good" }}})
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe I found it:

```
 db.getCollection('[collection]')find({ myList: 
 { $all: [ 
        {$elemMatch : { "status" : "good" }}, 
        {$elemMatch : {"doneBy" : "System"}} 
         ] 
  } })
```